# Get file size from html5 drag an drop folder

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drag-and-drop

I want to implement drag and drop of a folder and read all the files and their content. This is pretty straight forward. 
However, in order to track the upload progress, I need the file size, but it is not present in the `File` object, I tried looking into the `__proto__` but nothing.
Has someone any idea how to get it? Thanks

```
function traverseFileTree(item, path) {
  path = path || "";
  if (item.isFile) {
    // Get file
    item.file(function(file) {
      console.log(file.size); // undefined
    });
  } else if (item.isDirectory) {
    // Get folder contents
    var dirReader = item.createReader();
    dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
      for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        traverseFileTree(entries[i], path + item.name + "/");
      }
    });
  }
}

dropArea.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var items = event.dataTransfer.items;
  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (item) {
      traverseFileTree(item);
    }
  }
}, false);
```